# Filter ACF Post Object by Current Taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, filter, advanced-custom-fields

I have a post Object field, set to display within the default Wordpress categories. (Using Advanced Custom Fields in Wordpress).

However, I need to set a filter on this field, to only display posts that are within the current taxonomy.

So if I'm in a the category "books" in the admin panel, and I click the post object field, I should only see posts in the Books category.

This needs to be done dynamically, because the same ACF post object field displays in each category taxonomy.

I think this is done using the `acf/fields/post_object/query` filter (as per the post here: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/dynamically-set-taxonomy-filter-for-post-object-field/) but I can't get their suggested code to work on a basic level, filtering just by the current term.

This is what I have so far:

```
function filter_by_category( $args, $field, $post_id ) {
            
        // And adjust the query to filter by specific taxonomy term
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                'field'     => 'term_id',
                'terms'     => $post_id,
            ),
        );
    }
    return $args;
}

add_filter('acf/fields/post_object/query', 'filter_by_category');
```

There's probably an obvious mistake here, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.

```
function filter_by_category( $args, $field, $post_id ) {
     
    // $post_id comes in here as term_# so we need to remove 'term_' to get the term ID
    $prefix = 'term_';
    
    // Also if you are creating a new taxonomy, post_id = 'term_0' so then there's no point in adding a filter
    if ( 'term_0' != $post_id && substr( $post_id, 0, strlen( $prefix )) == $prefix ) {
        // Set $term_id to the ID part of $post_id
        $term_id = substr( $post_id, strlen( $prefix ) );
        
        // And adjust the query to filter by specific taxonomy term
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                'field'     => 'term_id',
                'terms'     => $term_id,
            ),
        );
    }
    return $args;

}

add_filter('acf/fields/post_object/query', 'filter_by_category');
```

Comment: Was searching for this cheers ! And I would get dynamically the taxonomy : 

$term = get_term($term_id);
$taxonomy = $term->taxonomy;

So that my code works for this field which is applied to multiple taxonomies :)